# Centering xymatrix in equation environment

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, matrices

The `xymatrix` diagram does not seem to vertically align when grouped in an equation environment.  For example, this code produces the following image (which seems to place the `xymatrix` 2.5em lower than it should be).  How can I remedy this without using `\raisebox{2.5em}`?

```
\[\boxed{
\begin{array}{ccc}
A & B & C \\
A & B & C \\
A & B & C \\
A & B & C \\
A & B & C \\
\end{array}
}
\quad 
\boxed{
\begin{array}{ccc}
A & B & C \\
A & B & C \\
A & B & C \\
A & B & C \\
A & B & C \\
\end{array}
}
\qquad\boxed{
\xymatrix@-1pc{
A & B & C \\
A & B & C \\
A & B & C \\
}}
\]
```

[image: Example diagram]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `\vcenter` to vertically center within math mode.  For some strange reason is seems to require (at least sometimes) an inner `\vbox`.  As in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
  x\,
   \vcenter{\vbox{
   \xymatrix@-1pc{
   A & B & C \\
   A & B & C \\
   A & B & C \\
   }
   }}
 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

As an aside, your example doesn't compile for me because I don't know where the `\boxed` command is from.  You should give a complete LaTeX (or TeX) file in your questions.

Comment: Also `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` could be used.

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks; I've just been copying that along for years since I first read it somewhere.  I don't really get why it's necessary.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I think it's defined in the amsmath package

Comment: With amsmath there's an easier way: `\begin{gathered}\xymatrix{...}\end{gathered}`

Comment: I tried `gathered`, and it didn't work for me.