# Extra whitespace at top of xymatrix

Tags: spacing, xy-pic

I'm making some slides where I want to show permutations with little diagrams of dots and arrows. Here is my attempt to depict the permutation 12345 --> 31245:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[ \left( \xymatrix@R=1 em@C=1 em{ \bullet \ar[rrd] & \bullet \ar[ld] & \bullet \ar[ld] & \bullet \ar[d] & \bullet \ar[d]  \\ \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet } \right) \]
\end{document}
```

As you can see, there is a lot of white space at the top. How can I get the height of the `xymatrix` to only go up to the top of the dots?

Comment: Would you be willing to use a different approach (using another package instead of `xy`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in where the reference point of the matrix is placed.

Rather than going with primitive commands, I suggest using `gathered`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[
\left(
  \!\begin{gathered}
  \xymatrix@R=1em@C=1em{
   \bullet \ar[rrd] & \bullet \ar[ld] & \bullet \ar[ld] & \bullet \ar[d] & \bullet \ar[d] \\
   \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet
   }
  \end{gathered}
\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

This comes handy also when a diagram must go in a numbered equation, for the same reason. The `\!` is necessary because of a “feature” in `amsmath`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a way, using [this trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15339/centering-xymatrix-in-equation-environment).

```
\[ \left( \vcenter{\vbox{ \xymatrix@R=1 em@C=1 em{ \bullet \ar[rrd] & \bullet \ar[ld] & \bullet \ar[ld] & \bullet \ar[d] & \bullet \ar[d]  \\ \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet }}} \right) \]
```

I have to admit I'm not clear on why this works. I understand that this places the midline of the `xymatrix` on the text base line, which is also a good thing to do, but I don't know why the `\left(`, `\right)` pair in the previous example reached up above the base line to compensate for the xymatrix being top aligned.